# Is it possible to use Google Cloud CDN with App Engine Standard environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-cdn

I see no way to connect my app engine backends with Cloud CDN. Seems like it's only available when using Compute Engine directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not currently possible. Currently, Google Cloud CDN can be used only to serve content that originates from Cloud Storage buckets, Compute Engine instance groups, and Compute Engine network endpoint groups. I agree that it would make sense to support App Engine Standard, too!

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

Currently in beta is [Serverless NEGs (Network Endpoint Groups)](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-serverless-negs) which will allow you to use App Engine behind a [HTTP(S) Load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https) and give you all the features provided with that including CDN

**Original**

Yes, App Engine will serve content via Google Cloud CDN as long as a cacheable response is returned.

Try setting the [`Cache-Control`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/reference/request-response-headers#headers_added_or_replaced) header to something like `max-age=86400, public` and ensuring a `Set-Cookie` header is not sent with the response

Comment: Hi @Craig are you sure, do you have any documentation that proves this?

Comment: @dendog I have not seen any documentation stating this, I actually came across this when trying to debug why a file wasn't changing.

Comment: @Hoff It was not in the browser cache, I could see the requests to app engine in stackdriver logging with an instance id of -1

Comment: @Craig how do you configure the CDN to serve App Engine app?

Comment: @MeLight Your application needs to send a cacheable response via the Cache-Control header

Comment: @craig any advice on what to search for the make this configuration? Would love the help.

Comment: @franciscojavierarceo There isn't really any documentation available for my original answer. But with the introduction of Serverless NEGs you should have a better supported way of using the CDN in App Engine